# UINavigationBar's title and right button misplaced when device orientation change

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm facing a really wired issue and having no idea what's causing that issue. Let me explain the issue in detail,

**General detail**
I have a UINavigationBar on top and it works fine with the single orientation. But when I rotate the device, title and right button don't get fit accordingly. Below are my cases,

**Case 1:**
When I run the app in Portrait mode, NavigationBar appears fine
[image]

But when I change the orientation to Landscape, this occurs
[image]

**Case 2:**
When I run in Landscape mode, NavigationBar appears fine
[image]

But if I change the orientation to Portrait, this appears
[image]

**Note:** I'm using `Autolayout` and below is the code for title and `UIBarButtonItems`,

```
self.title = @"Title";

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(navigateToPreviouseScreen)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addButtonTapped)];
```

Comment: What kind of constraint apply on these parts?

Comment: Are you manually adding a UINavigationBar? Never see something like this with UINavigationController

Comment: @merge I'm not using any constraints for them as they are `UIBarButtonItems` in UINavigationBar.

Comment: @vk.edward.li No, I'm not adding it manually. I just made Push segue from `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController`

Comment: Can you show me more code on ViewControlelr?

Comment: @merge There is no other code related to `UINavigation` . Just other business logics.

Comment: It's strange for me. What is iOS version you use?

Comment: I'm testing it iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.1 .

Answer (score 0):

I simply used your code to configure the Navigation bar in *viewDidLoad* and didn't add any constraints. It works perfectly fine on my side. Did you manually add constraints?

Comment: No, I didn't add any constraints for these buttons or title.

Answer (score 0):

try translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO, it solve your problem or not

and if not
also try this 
your_right_bar_button.customview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight